# Регулярное выражение на проверку адреса сайта на php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день! Нужно регулярное выражение на адрес сайта, которое будет учитывать в том числе и адреса состоящие из русских букв. Ну и чтобы общие вещи поддерживались, оба протокола и так далее

Comment: Добрый, цена вопроса?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что SO - не фриланс биржа.

Comment: Причем тут фриланс, это вопрос с которым сталкивается почти каждый веб разработчик ? данная информация будет полезна всем. Про комментарий согласен, он не в тему, но зачем вопрос то закрывать?

Answer (score 1):

В общем схема простая и легко реализуемая. Для начала заходим на [Google](https://google.com) и ищем там ответ на свой вопрос. В вашем случае наибраем там подобное:

> [url regex](https://www.google.ru/search?q=url%20regex)

Переходим по [первой ссылке](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) и находим там список уже готовых регулярок. По таблице находим наиболее правильную и вставляем к себе в код:

```
<?php
$regexp = '_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS';

$url = 'http://проверь.меня.рф/хаха?query=dogs+and+cats';

echo 'URL is ', preg_match($regexp, $url) ? 'correct' : 'incorrect';
```

Вот пример результатов проверки различных URL этой регуляркой: https://repl.it/N9Gy/0

Comment: и всё же не рекомендовал бы такие регулярки без явной необходимости. Простых проверок на https?:// или filter_var зачастую вполне хватает